# Send/receive USSD using SMPP

Tags: c#, .net, smpp, ussd

I want to send and receive USSD message using SMPP protocol and looking for a .NET library for this job. Does anybody have any experience for this job?

Comment: _Does anybody have any experience for this job?_ Did you try anything first?

Comment: I found some libraries like easy smpp but haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 2):

Inetlab is a great and is capable of doing it. I have not used the USSD portion but I know the general SMPP class works great.

[Inetlab Link](http://www.inetlab.com/)

Comment: Do you have any experience on it?

Comment: Not with the USSD but I have used the SMPP PDU code as the company I work for is a WASP. I went through many libraries out there and Inetlab is really one of the most complete and it is also in C#

Answer (score 0):

I check [Easy SMPP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/easysmpp/), it was great and implement sending and receiving SMS over SMPP completely.
I have added USSD support to that and will explain it in my blog soon.

Comment: No USSD support yet ehsan?